# Recursive Multiplier in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive multiplier in ruby.

```
@j = 0

def multiplier(x, y, z)
    count = 0
    if x > 0
        if z > 0
            @j += y
            z -= 1
            count += 1
            multiplier(x, y, z)
        else
            x -= 1
            z = count
            p z
            multiplier(x, y, z)
        end
    else
        return @j
    end
end


def main
    puts "Calculation is: " + multiplier(3, 10, 4).to_s
end

main
```

X is how many times the multiplication happens

Y is the number we want to multiply

Z is the number we multiply by

The code *should* output **120** with the variables that are there

I am having issues getting Z to stay what I need it to be. Also, I'd prefer to do this without a global variable

So something like x*(y*z) but without the times symbol

Comment: i am confused ... does `x * y * z` always get the correct solution? (which, by the way, is the same as `x * (y * z)`) .. Because that seems at odds with your explanation of the variables.

Comment: x*(y*z) will always get the correct answer. Take the variables that are present in the code. x: 3, y: 10, z: 4 ==> 3*(10*4) ==> 3*(40) ==> 120. What do you think are at odds?

Comment: Ok I get what you are asking. I think the key thing is you want to do this without the times symol, maybe you  should make that more explicit that it's part of the requirement.

Comment: I though recursive multiplying is always without the time symbol. Also I made the comment at the end of my question to do it without the times symbol

Comment: Not sure why recursion is important but we can avoid the times symbol like this `Array.new(x,Array.new(y,z)).flatten.reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your code is `count` is a local variable, it is not saved between recursive calls. Also, if you want to avoid globals, pass the variable as an additional parameter in call to the function. In FP we call it *accumulator*:

```
def multiplier(x, y, z, j = 0)
  if z > 0
    multiplier(x, y, z - 1, j + y)
  elsif z.zero? # done with z, jump to x × (y × z)
    # z = -1 to explicitly mark we are done with z
    multiplier(x, j, -1, 0)
  elsif y.zero? # yay, we are all set, reducing is done!
    j
  else
    # still doing x × result step
    multiplier(x, y - 1, -1, j + x)
  end
end

multiplier(3, 10, 4)
#⇒ 120
```

The above surely lacks necessary checks for input validity, but I bet you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks. This is great

Comment: Personally I would omit the `0` in line 6: `multiplier(x, j, -1)`. It's functionally the same, of course. I think the key point in this answer, which you hinted at, is that this function is **pure** - i.e. there are no side-effects, so you'll always get the same result for a given input -- unlike OP's original version, which manipulates a "global" variable to accumulate the result.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the idiomatic way in ruby is using iterators instead of recursion/cycles

```
def multiplier(x, y, z)
  x.times.map do
    y.times.map do
      z
    end.reduce(:+)
  end.reduce(:+)
end
```

or

```
def multiplier(x, y, z)
  x.times.map do
    y.times.map do
      z
    end
  end.flatten.reduce(:+)
end
```

Or if the only operation is `inc`

```
def multiplier(x, y, z)
  j = 0
  x.times do
    y.times do
      z.times do
        j += 1
      end
    end
  end
  j
end
```

the output is the same

```
multiplier(3, 10, 4)
# 120
```

For an arbitrary number of args we have to use recursion

```
def multiplier(*xs, res: 0)
  return res if xs.empty?
  xs[0].times do
    res += 1 if xs.size == 1
    res = multiplier(*xs.drop(1), res: res)
  end
  res
end
```

or

```
def multiplier(*xs, res: 0)
  head, *tail = xs
  head.to_i.times do
    res += 1 if tail.empty?
    res = multiplier(*tail, res: res)
  end
  res
end
```

Comment: Terrible space complexity, though :) (for the first two)

Comment: the first one is `O(max(x,y))`, the second one is `O(x*y)` and the last `O(1)`, I suppose. Good thing to be considered, thx @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `times.map` → `times.lazy.map` and it’s `O(1)` everywhere :shrug:

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin if performance is an issue then the last one should be the best choice, otherwise I would go the first or the second

Comment: With `lazy` enumerators they are _literally_ the same.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin it's a constant factor, but lazy is slower. the complexity is linear though

Comment: Can you think of a way to make this answer work for an arbitrary list of integers, not specifically 3 values? The only way I can think do it is with `eval`, but that's incredibly hacky: `result = 0; eval integers.reduce('result += 1') { |code, i| "#{i}.times { #{code} }" }; result`

Comment: @TomLord: why, it's easy. Even with some recursion :) https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/708e1ec8551dc63df43edf977f391776

Comment: @SergioTulentsev let's assume you have only `+1` operation :)

Comment: @fl00r: that snippet will benefit from a `head, *tail = xs` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nice destructuring

Comment: The first 2 examples could just be `Array.new(x,Array.new(y,z)).flatten.reduce(:+)`

Comment: @engineersmnky `Array.new(x,Array.new(y,(Array.new(z, 1)))).flatten.reduce(:+)` then :)

Comment: @engineersmnky but that's not idiomatic ;)

Comment: @fl00r you can do better than that...`Array.new(x,y).cycle(z).sum`

Answer (score 2):

Building on the [recursive answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52849727/1954610), here's a more generic function that can take an **arbitrarily long** list of positive integers and multiply them by recursive addition:

```
def multiplier(*integers, accum: 0)
  if integers.size == 1
    # We are finished!
    integers[0]
  elsif integers[-1].positive?
    # "Multiply" the last two integers, by recursive addition
    integers[-1] -= 1
    multiplier(*integers, accum: accum + integers[-2])
  else
    # The above multiplication is complete; set the last integer to its result
    integers[-2] = accum
    multiplier(*integers[0..-2])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by writing a method to multiply two numbers recursively:

```
def multiply_2(a, b)
  return 0 if a.zero?
  b + multiply_2(a - 1, b)
end

multiply_2(3, 4)
#=> 12
```

and build upon that method to multiply three numbers:

```
def multiply_3(a, b, c)
  multiply_2(multiply_2(a, b), c)
end

multiply_3(3, 4, 10)
#=> 3
```

and eventually extend that to handle *n* numbers:

```
def multiply_n(a, b, *more)
  result = multiply_2(a, b)
  return result if more.empty?
  multiply_n(result, *more)
end

multiply_n(3, 4, 10, 2)
#=> 240
```

Note that you might run into a `SystemStackError` for large numbers. This can be avoided by making `multiply_2` [*tail-recursive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (leaving that as an exercise, it's not hard) and enabling Ruby's `:tailcall_optimization`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be written thusly.

```
def multiplier(*args)
  prod = recurse(*args.map(&:abs))
  args.count { |n| n < 0 }.even? ? prod : -prod
end

def recurse(first, *rest)
  first.zero? || rest.empty? ? first : ([recurse(*rest)]*first).sum
end

multiplier(3,  10,  4)        #=>  120
multiplier(3,  10,  4, 2, 3)  #=>  720
multiplier(3, -10,  4)        #=> -120
multiplier(3, -10, -4)        #=>  120
multiplier(3,   0,  4)        #=>    0
multiplier(3,   0, -4)        #=>    0
```

Suppose we wish to compute `multiplier(3, -4)`. `recurse(3, 4)` is called, where

```
first = 3
rest = [4]
first.zero? #=> false
rest.empty? #=> false
```

so we compute

```
([recurse(4)]*3).sum
```

In `recurse(4)`,

```
first = 4
rest = []
```

As `rest.empty #=> true`, `recurse` returns `first #=> 4`, so

```
([recurse(4)]*3).sum]
  #=> ([4]*3).sum => [4,4,4].sum => 12
```

is returned to `multiplier`. As `[3, -4]` contains an odd number of negative values, multiplier returns `-12`.

Comment: So as the avoid the dreaded times symbol (albeit `Array#*` not `Integer#*`) one could use `[recurse(*rest)].cycle(first).sum` other benefit is that this need not build additional `Array`s

Comment: @engineersmnky, I've never seen `cycle` used with an argument. I'll have to remember that. Gee, I hope the OP did not intend that answers avoid all uses of the asterisk.